# UE4 - Macroing UHT Macros

Tags: c++, macros, unreal-engine4

currently I'm trying to reduce how much menial code I have to write (Because I need about 28 of these things) and make the code neater to look at and nicer to manage.

Right now I want this

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintNativeEvent) 
    void OnInputShootDown(); 
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintNativeEvent) 
    void OnInputShootUp();
```

and I'm using this to try and get there

```
#define INPUT_DEFINITION(inputName) \
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintNativeEvent) \
    void OnInput##inputName##Down(); \
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintNativeEvent) \
    void OnInput##inputName##Up();
```

But I think MY macro is being expanded in a way that erases the UHT macros, also, even if this did work, you need a newline after the UHT macros for them to work which I also don't know how to do. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this or do I have to just suck it up and type everything out?

Comment: UHT doesn't read preprocessed code, so you can't use macros for them. Sorry.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld, alrighty, thanks for replying so quickly :)